# Clean the workspace .metadata folder on product startup

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I develop an Eclipse plugin which extends to Eclipse UI, and we deliver it as a whole Eclipse product. The plugin has as a target some automotive projects.

The version of the product can be configured from the project and executing a batch file will launch the proper version of the product.

So the final command will be something like this:

```
start /B %PRODUCT_PATH%/eclipse.exe -clean -configuration %PATH_TO_PROJECT_CONFIG% -data %PROJECT_PATH
```

The problem comes when switching from one product version to another, the `.metadata` folder is corrupted or the information from it is not compatible between products, I am not sure what happens exactly but I get sporadic exceptions at startup.

When I clean the `.metadata` and launch the product without an existing `.metadata` folder in the project location, everything runs normally.

Is there an command line option for Eclipse to clean the workspace `.metadata` before startup?

Comment: Maybe the only solution is a start script which removes the `.metadata` dir  and the call `eclipse.exe`...

Comment: @Lii This one came to my mind already, but I expected some `eclipse` command line option

Answer (score 3):

All (I think!) the Eclipse command line arguments can be found in the [*Runtime options*](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) section of the reference documentation.

I find nothing in that document about removing the `.metadata`directory.

I have also searched for usage of the words "clean", "clear" and "remove", and reference to `osgi.instance.area` (which and think is the OSGI term for the `.metadata` directory) and found nothing that seems relevant.

#### Suggestion 1: `clearPersistedState`

You could try `-clearPersistedState` option. Maybe that could help? (I don' really know the purpose of the option, I just found it in the documentation.)

#### Suggestion 2: Start script

Otherwise maybe you could have a start script which simply runs `del` to remove the directory.

#### Suggestion 3: Find the root cause

The best thing to do is of course to find the root cause of the startup problems and solve that. But maybe that is too time consuming or impossible in your case.

Comment: 1. `clearPersistedState` reffers to the changes done by the user.  3. The root cause may be eclipse itself. If you try to use a workspace generated with an older eclipse version, even eclipse itself throws a warning that you shouldn't do that..

Answer (score 1):

The `.metadata` folder of the worksapce does not only contain caches but also the local history, the layout of the perspectives with their editors and views, and non-shared launch configurations are stored in the `.metadata` folder. Therefore deleting the `.metadata` folder is not a good idea.

**Instead of cleaning the whole `.metadata` folder** find the root cause, the files causing the problem and **write code that discards or migrates these data** to the new format. The [Eclipse bug 411602](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=411602) is an example of such an issue that was caused by not migrated data stored in the `.metadata` folder.